# Html.BeginForm not passing parameter

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms, razor, drop-down-menu

I have the following code that populates a Drop Down List and auto submits a form but it’s not passing the id back to the controller.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#ArticleID").change(function () {
            $('#TheForm').submit();
        });
    });
</script>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Details", "Article", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "TheForm" })){
    @Html.DropDownList("ArticleID", (SelectList)ViewBag.ArticleId, "Select Article") 
}
```

I get:

```
/Article/Details
```

But need:

```
/Article/Details/1
```

I’m following a tutorial that stops at this point. I’m not quite sure what is going on here regarding `TheForm` I tried to put `ArticleID` but that didn’t work. How do I do this?

---

I've also tried it without jQuery like this,

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Details", "Article", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "TheForm" })){

@Html.DropDownList(
"ArticleID",
(SelectList)ViewData["Articles"],
"Please Select an Article",
     new
     {
         onchange = "document.getElementById('TheForm').submit();"
     })
 }
```

But it doesn't send the parameter through either.

Comment: What do your routes look like?

Comment: I only have the default route in my Global.asax {controller}/{action}/{id} for my home controller but this is using a different controller, should the above code work if I have everything else set up correctly???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The url is determined before the page is rendered in the following line:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Details", "Article", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "TheForm" }))
```

which renders:

```
<form action="/Article/Details" id="TheForm" method="post">
```

Since the value that you want to add to the Url, `ArticleID`, is determined by the dropdown selection, you'll need to manipulate the `action` attribute of the form using JavaScript.

Something like this would probably work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#ArticleID").change(function () {
            // The following line was changed to use @naspinski's suggestion
            var actionUrl = '@Url.Action("Details", "Article")/' + $('#ArticleID').val();
            $('#TheForm').attr('action', actionUrl);
            $('#TheForm').submit();
        });
    });
</script>
```

With that said, this feel awkward to me.  It may be worth considering how that value needs or will be used.  Does it really need to be part of a route?  If not, you can avoid this manipulating the `action` attribute altogether.

Comment: If that’s the case why would someone who is very well versed in MVC put a tutorial together with the above code, if you can do anything with it?

Comment: Also if it’s a POST why can’t I simply retrieve the id in the control, I thought that’s what POST does?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something.  Is the tutorial available online?  The reason you can't retrieve `id` in the control is because it is not available: it is not in the route and it is not in the POSTed data.  The code I provided makes the `id` part of the url (so it becomes part of the route).  If you don't care what the url looks like, you can retrieve the `id` value by using `articleId` as the parameter instead of `id`, since `ArticleId` is what is being POSTed.

Comment: Hi John, I understand you hack and it is the clsoest I’ve come to getting it to work but with the combination of MVC URL mixed in with jQuery Mobile it only works once.

Comment: Also here is the tutorial: http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/128/Get-The-Drop-On-ASP.NET-MVC-DropDownLists

Comment: Great hack John. I was finally able to make it work  by making all the go back links physical or is it virtual, e.g.. the back button now has a link to http://www.mysite.com/mymobilesite/Articles and so on. Cheers.

Comment: Finally got a chance to look at the tutorial. It doesn't look like the author intended for the dropdown value to be part of the route. It was just demonstrating a way to submit the form automatically when the dropdown changes.  Anyway, I'm glad you found a solution and glad I could be of help.

Comment: @Url.Action will render your route correctly, you just need to tack the id on the end.

Answer (score 1):

There is a built in way to render this without selecting the action:

```
var actionUrl = '@Url.Action("Details", "Article")/' + $('#ArticleID').val();
```

Comment: they want to do a post though, if the url string is too long the post will fail